# python setup.py question

Tags: python, setup.py

So I have a folder structure something like this:

```
pckA - core
     - io
pckB - core
     - io
     - main
```

Now I have to create a setup.py file for both there packages. My current approach is :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import setuptools

setup(
    name='ProjectExternals',
    version='0.1dev',
    packages=["pckA","pckA.core","pckA.io","pckB","pckB.core","pckB.io","pckB.main"],
    license='Not decided yet',
    author='',
    author_email='',
    long_description="",
    install_requires=["numpy","quantities"]
)
```

This setup.py is located in the same folder as pckA and pckB .So my question is : is it necessary to add all the subpackages like pckA.core etc or does setuptools know to install these as well?

Comment: The title of this question is very generic, could you rephrase it to help discoverability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if you just want the whole package, specifying its name (i.e. `pckA`) is enough - no need to list all the modules in it. `distutils` will recursively discover them.

So in your case:

```
packages=['pckA', 'pckB'],
```

Does the trick. Here's a quote from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html):

> The packages option tells the
>   Distutils to process (build,
>   distribute, install, etc.) all pure
>   Python modules found in each package
>   mentioned in the packages list. In
>   order to do this, of course, there has
>   to be a correspondence between package
>   names and directories in the
>   filesystem.

---

If you *don't* want whole packages but would rather include only specific modules, use the `py_modules` option instead.

Comment: Note that submodules in a package are included but not subpackages.